# How can I add commandArgument dynamically to a LinkButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to add a "download" button for each item in the panel list. Each download button should pass a unique ID to the event handler.

The problem with the new button : ID=DownloadPopup_btn_1 is that it does not send the request to the event handler with the argument I intended to.

I tried to use the <%#Eval()%> method but it either send the argument as an empty string or plain text "item.PromotionId" (depend if I used "" or not).

I can't use <%=item.PromotionId %> because "item" is not defined.

```
 <ul id="draggablePanelList" class="list-group">
            <% var popupIndex = 0;

                foreach (var item in OldGameSettings.PromotionalDataList)
                {
                    popupIndex++;
            %>

            <li class="list-group-item sortable-item first">

                <asp:LinkButton ID="DownloadPopup_btn_1" 
                                runat="server" 
                                CssClass="btn btn-default pull-right btn-xs"    
                                OnCommand="DownloadPopup_Click"
                                CommandArgument='<%#Eval(item.PromotionId)%>'>
                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>
                </asp:LinkButton>

                <span style="margin-right: 15px;" class="pull-right">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;" onclick="sendToTopPriority(this)" id="<%=item.PromotionId %>"></i>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;" onclick="sendToBottomPriority(this)" id="<%=item.PromotionId %>"></i>
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;" onclick="sendToPriority(this)" id="<%=item.PromotionId %>"></i>
                </span>
            </li>
            <% } %>
        </ul>
```

Expected: click on the N'ish download button in the panel list, the button will trigger the event handler with CommandArgument == Button[N].CommandArgument

Actual: click on the N'ish download button in the panel list, the button triggers the event handler with CommandArgument == not what I want...

P.S. I've added the last section in the code to prove that item.PromotionId works in a different elements.

Comment: `CommandArgument == not what I want...` what exactly you are getting in `CommandArgument` ?

Comment: You can try `<%=item.PromotionId %>` instead of `'<%#Eval(item.PromotionId)%>`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i'm getting either an empty string or the plain text of <%=item.PromotionId %>. I tried what you suggested but item is not known at this context.

Comment: @EtianChamay, Are you using server-side events like Page_Load etc. in your code or its 100% inline C# code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try use a repeater control

```
<ul id="draggablePanelList" class="list-group">    
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptOutter"  >
        <ItemTemplate>

                <li class="list-group-item sortable-item first">

                    <asp:LinkButton ID="DownloadPopup_btn_1" 
                                    runat="server" 
                                    CssClass="btn btn-default pull-right btn-xs"    
                                    OnCommand="DownloadPopup_Click"
                                    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("PromotionId")%>'>
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>
                    </asp:LinkButton>

                    <span style="margin-right: 15px;" class="pull-right">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;" onclick="sendToTopPriority(this)" id='<%#Eval("PromotionId")%>'></i>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;" onclick="sendToBottomPriority(this)" id='<%#Eval("PromotionId")%>'></i>
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;" onclick="sendToPriority(this)" id='<%#Eval("PromotionId")%>'></i>
                    </span>
                </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

don't forget to assign the repeater datasource to your  OldGameSettings.PromotionalDataList

**Code Behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        rptOutter.DataSource = OldGameSettings.PromotionalDataList;
        rptOutter.DataBind();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 CommandArgument='<%#Eval(item.PromotionId)%>'>
```

this line must be

```
 CommandArgument='<%#Eval("item.PromotionId")%>'>
```